# How to make GridView Item alignment to centre?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. In the below code, i need to align the `grid view` item based on the count, let's say the first row is filled with 3 items and 2nd row is filled with 2 items means my 2nd row items to be aligned centre to the first row and vice versa
2. All this says for the dynamic row count that fitting based on the device width.
3. Here with i attached the sample expected output

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1QdS.jpg)

```
class SocialLoginWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SocialLoginWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28, right: 18, top: 22),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 100.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index == 4) { // Assuming itemCount is 5 and index is zero-based
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      itemCount: 5,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: **1)** Do you require fixed size for the items? **2)** Is the number of items per row fixed? **3)** In your screenshot, it seems like what you need is a [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) or a [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html), not a `GridView`. `GridView` is more if you need scrolling

Comment: @ Dhafin Rayhan, Its only fixed size but not fixed items per row, however i completed using the ```Wrap``` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget instead and set crossAxisAlignment to center.

I don't believe this is possible using GridView.

Comment: Yup, i preferred ```Wrap```